# Powershell Error when Running process

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

I am working in C# working on a program to clean up the windows 10 start menu and assign a custom layout. To do so I need to run a single command from powershell and am getting an error when running it.

How I am trying to accomplish the task.

I am starting C:\.\.\powershell.exe and passing the -command arguments of: Import-StartLayout -LayoutPath C:\StartMenu.xml -MountPath C:\

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @" -command Import-StartLayout -LayoutPath C:\StartMenu.xml -MountPath C:\";
process.Start();
```

---

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
Import-StartLayout : The term 'Import-StartLayout' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-StartLayout -LayoutPath C:\StartMenu.xml -MountPath C:\; Start ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Import-StartLayout:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any ideas why cmd or powershell will not take the external cmdlet of Import-StartLayout??

Comment: which version of windows are the test pc

Comment: Does the PS script work being run from the PowerShell CLI interface?

Comment: "*How I am trying to accomplish the task*" - where's that bit? How are you running PowerShell?

Comment: @zwork it does. I run the script when debugging in visual studio and it runs without error. When I build and run it on a clean build of 10 it breaks.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Sorry, it has been added to the post. I am using Process process = new Process(); to call in the file to run and pass in arguments.

Comment: The reason that you need to use 64-bit Powershell (via sysnative) is because the cmdlet Import-StartLayout is part of the StartLayout module. If you attempt to import-module StartLayout on 32-bit x86 Powershell, it wont work. Please try to use 64-bit powershell.

Answer (score -1):

`Import-StartLayout` does not exist on windows 7 and earlier if you know that, continue.
You could try using `System.Diagnostics.Process` like the following:

```
Process powerShell = new Process()
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        Arguments = "Import-StartLayout -LayoutPath C:\\StartMenu.xml -MountPath C:\\",
        FileName = "powershell"
    }
};
powerShell.Start();
```

Another way would be to use [`System.Management.Automation`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation/) which is not an official supported package by Microsoft.

```
using (Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
    runSpace.Open();
    using (Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline())
    {
        Command importStartLayout = new Command("Import-StartLayout");
        importStartLayout.Parameters.Add("LayoutPath", "C:\\StartMenu.xml");
        importStartLayout.Parameters.Add("MountPath", "C:\\");
        pipeline.Commands.Add(importStartLayout);
        Collection<PSObject> resultsObjects = pipeline.Invoke();

        StringBuilder resultString = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject obj in resultsObjects)
        {
            resultString.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: /C or /K doesn't work because it's a Powershell command and not a CMD command.